# Como autofiltrar con ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-repeat

Estoy tratando de hacer un autofiltro pero cuando coloco los valores, este los toma pero no hace el filtrado de datos el codigo que uso es el siguiente..

el filtro esta aqui ->

```
<input type="text" id="{{item.descripcion}}" ng-model="searchinput" style="color:black" value="{{item.descripcion}}" readonly>
```

y pasa que no toma el value para filtrar los datos aunque si se setea el valor , solo funciona cuando le escribo datos dentro del input

alguien me puede orientar ?

```
      <div class="box  box-solid collapsed-box " id="oficinas" ng-repeat="item in claves">

                        <div  class="box-header" data-widget="collapse" onclick="asignar()">



                            <h2 class="box-title" display="block" style="float:left; margin-left:2%;"> {{item.documentos}} </h2>
                            <img class="change" src="css/galeria/down.png" style="float:right; width:7%;margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 4%;" />

                            <p id="typee" value="{{item.descripcion}}"></p>
                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body" id="uniq" ng-controller="detalle_referenciacontrol">
                            <!--aqui esta el filtro-->
<input type="text" id="{{item.descripcion}}" ng-model="searchinput" style="color:black" value="{{item.descripcion}}" readonly>                          
                            <center>

<table class="table table-hover" style="margin:auto">
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in itemsarchivo | filter:{tipodescrip:searchinput}" id="{{item.path}}" onclick="ver(this)">
                                            <td><b style="float:left;">{{item.nombre}}</b></td>
                                            <td style="text-align:right"><img src="css/galeria/doc.png"></td> 


                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Me gustaría poder ayudarte, pero tu código está incompleto... deberías subir el controlador y el html a plnkr, por ejemplo para que podamos ver el código funcionando y poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola no puedo subirlo a plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con algo como esto

```
ng-repeat="item in itemsarchivo | filter:searchinput"
```

Puedes ver más opciones y detalles de filtros aquí 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Hola asi es como lo estoy usando

Comment: No, tú lo tienes ng-repeat="item in itemsarchivo | filter:{tipodescrip:searchinput}"